# How to read authenticated WMS using GDAL Java Bindings OpenEX?

Tags: gdal, wms, authentication

I would like to read Raster tiles from a WMS endpoint, download them/it as geotifs, then do stuff with them. The WMS endpoint has UN and PW authentication.
I am using the GDAL Java bindings, and I'm getting a 401 on my request.
I don't know the convention for putting the UN and PW into the options, or I am missing something completely. I'm new to GDAL.

Here is my code

```
public class WMS {
       static {
        gdal.AllRegister();
        System.out.println("registered GDAL");
      }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        Vector options = new Vector();
        options.add(0,"some UN");//????
        options.add(1,"some PW");//???
        Dataset d =  gdal.OpenEx("https://some/wms/",1L,new Vector(), options);
       
      }
    }
```

Comment: What does that vector stuff have to do with WMS?

Comment: @user30184 A vector is just a Java data type... not a geospatial vector. The Vector object is an arg to the OpenEx method. I had a hunch that some type of convention is required for putting the un and pw into that vector object (which I named options)